# Border line not appearing in Outlook/Gmail

Tags: html, css

I am creating a HTML signature and it appears that my border line is not appearing in my email client (outlook/Gmail) when its appearing in the web version.

The css style code is here:

```
.border {
        border-right: solid 1px #8E8E8E;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        max-width: 560px;
    }
    </style>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="border"><a href="http://busways.com.sg/"><img src="http://busways.com.sg/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Busways-Official-Logo.png" title="Busways Official Website" alt="Busways Logo" width="150"></a></td>
    <td class="Content"><font class="name">Benjamin</font><br>
        <font class="designation">Executive</font><br>
        <span class="details"><b>TEL:</b> 6123456</span>  <span class="details"><b>FAX:</b> 64567243</span>  <span class="details"><b>EMAIL:</b> admin@</span><br>
        <span class="details"><b>WEB:</b> website</span>  <span class="details"><b>ADD:</b> address</span>
        </td>
     </tr>
        
    </table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to have the line of the border to show in outlook and gmAIL server?

Answer (score 1):

Use inline-styling for signatures. I removed the class `border`, the external css and just added inline styling:

```html
<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="border-right: solid 1px #8e8e8e; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; max-width: 560px"><a href="http://busways.com.sg/"><img src="http://busways.com.sg/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Busways-Official-Logo.png" title="Busways Official Website" alt="Busways Logo" width="150"></a></td>
    <td class="Content"><font class="name">Benjamin</font><br>
        <font class="designation">Executive</font><br>
        <span class="details"><b>TEL:</b> 6123456</span>  <span class="details"><b>FAX:</b> 64567243</span>  <span class="details"><b>EMAIL:</b> admin@</span><br>
        <span class="details"><b>WEB:</b> website</span>  <span class="details"><b>ADD:</b> address</span>
        </td>
     </tr>
        
    </table>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance! Can I also check if there is a way to have this email signature mobile responsive? So when in smaller screen, it will be stacked top and bottom instead of the current side by side layout.